# Unable to shutdown windows 8

Tags: windows-8, shutdown, windows-update

I have a problem. Since last weekend when some updates where done (and didn't finish successfully) I'm unable to shutdown my OS. Whenever I try to reboot, shutdown or hibernate, I get a blackscreen (as I should) and after that, my laptop doesn't shutdown, instead it gets back to login screen.

(It is ofc possible to hard shutdown it and to get it to stan-by without any problem) Funny thing is that system after hard shutdown does without any problem boot back up, but just refuse to shutdown.

Later I tried to hibernate it through cmd command:

```
shutdown /f /h
```

and after that console throws back:

```
The Configuration Registry Database Is Corrupt.(1009)
```

Already tried sfc /scannow few times, as well as chkdsk, without any success.

Anybody familiar with such error, and know any means of repairing it? (Format C:, is an option but as last resort)

Comment: try redoing the updates while logged on - not sure how it works on windows 8 but its possible in windows 7. This is what I do when I get a stuck update and after a few repeats it fixes it

Comment: Tried already, but when I do, they install and after reboot they rollback, and so back and forth, I've disabled windows update service after it doing so few times

Comment: "Already tried sfc /scannow few times, as well as chkdsk,"  Good to hear!  But what were the results?  Did SFC or Chkdsk claim they repaired anything?

Comment: chkdsk didn't found anything to repair
sfc prompted that there was something it couldn't repair but didn't really say what was that